# Filtering the data displayed in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django application that shows all the users registered. However, I would like to filter the users displayed dynamically. For example, if I select Male from a dropdown list, I want the application to display only Males.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I did not include any code because it is just a scenario.

Thank you!

Comment: Use can use Django filter https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!